# OnEdit() function runs only when I run the script manually

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I've created a spreadsheet and added some values, I'm trying to capture the timestamp of the last edited cell within a range of cells. The below script does this job perfectly but only when I run the script manually that is when I press the "run" button in the editor, but that sort of defeats the purpose. What am I missing?

My code:

```
function OnEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  if(r.getColumn() > 7 && r.getColumn() <= 13 && ss.getName()=='Moto') { 
  var celladdress ='Q'+ r.getRowIndex() 
  ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
};
```

Comment: You're missing having read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started)

Answer (score 1):

The function name should be `onEdit` -- notice the `o` is lowercase. Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  if(r.getColumn() > 7 && r.getColumn() <= 13 && ss.getName()=='Moto') { 
    var celladdress ='Q'+ r.getRowIndex() 
    ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the edit.  I got mixed up for a moment.  I need to be more careful

Answer (score 1):

This is the same function taking advantage of the event object.  I assumed that you mispelled onEdit() when you moved it to SO since it wouldn't run otherwise. The format string should be `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm`

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.columnStart > 7 && e.range.columnStart <= 13 && sh.getName()=='Moto') { 
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,17).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
  }
}
```

The onEdit trigger only fires on User Edits.

[simple date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but won't this replace the value of the range that is edited?

Comment: You are correct.  I have a tendency to answer the question before I read it carefully.